# Advise needed UK visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk

How can I stay for eight months in London on a two year UK visitor VISA with multiple entries not exceeding 180 days.

Comment: Do you mean you want to stay for 8 months continuous? Like January to August?  As a normal visitor you can't do that, but what is your reason? It may be one of a few special exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

AIUI

You can only spend 6 months in the UK on any one entry.

There is no formal limit on the number of entries or their cumulative length but there is a rule that people on visitor visas (or visa-free visitor entries) must not try to "live in the UK" through "frequently or successive visits".

The result is that trying to exit and quickly re-enter to extend your stay is a risky move. The border gaurd *can* let you back in with a new 6 months stamp but they *can* also decide that you are spending too much time in the UK and/or that they suspect your activities in the UK are not within those allowed on a standard visitor visa and kick you out.

Comment: In addition, you need to explain how you are going to support yourself in London without working for the duration of each planned visit.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, 8 months without going back to your home country? if it is yes then it's impossible. I believe that it is a total of six months in 12 so if you leave after 2 months then come back you still have 4 months to visit again. If you overstay then you will have a conflict going back to the UK or reapplying for an any UK visa. Read more information [here](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa)

Comment: That’s wrong. If you leave after 2 months and come back and they let you in you get new 6 months. Not 4 months. As long as your visa is valid beyond that

Comment: Hi Hanky, they will not grant you another 6 months when you visit again.  Is it valid for 6 months right? example your visa approved by February 1, 2018, and it will expire on July 01, 2018 you can visit and exit in the UK as long as it's not yet July 01, 2018.

Comment: Hey Miranda, that's true for a 6 month visa but OP holds a 2 year one. Which allows 6 months on any entry as long as those 6 months finish before the expiry date. So if the OP was in the UK for 2 months then left for 3 and came back then they get another 6 months if they are let in